# Adding invitees to Calendar event in-App

Tags: iphone, calendar, eventkit

I have an `EventViewController` that is shown modally to the user. While the user can add Title, Location, Recurrence and Alarms, there's  no option to add Invitees. However, within the Calendar app, one definitely can add Invitees. Why is adding invitees disabled within an app or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EKEventEditViewController to get full support for adding invitees. EKEventViewController is primarily for displaying events and has limited editing capabilities.